# How to parse this JSON in Java usin Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

The JSON is :

```
    {
  "statuses": [
    {
      "created_at": "Fri Dec 02 17:05:40 +0800 2016",
      "id": 4048283825629844,
      "mid": "4048283825629844",
      "user": {
        "id": 5680719858,
        "idstr": "5680719858",
        "class": 1
        },
      "is_show_bulletin": 2
    },
    .......
```

I don't know the "user" key is what kind of Java object type.

Please give me a sample code to show how to parse this json. Many thanks!

Comment: get the element 0 of the array statuses, the the object user, then val for key id, idstr, class

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know the "user" key is what kind of java object type.

It isn't a Java standard library class. It's a user defined POJO. The Gson documentation discusses these.

For example, this post shows a similar `User` class.

[Mapping JSON into POJO using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039511/mapping-json-into-pojo-using-gson)

It is up to you to create the wrapper objects, with the correct fields as necessary, or use generators such as http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Answer (score -1):

Download Google Gson.jar from here

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.html

Then add the following code to your java file

```
import com.google.gson.Gson; // import this package
```

and then you can try this

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
string jsondata = gson.toJson("your object"); // pass your object here it will convert to json
```

for reverse you can do this

gson.fromJson("your json string", "your class");

Comment: That doesn't *parse* the JSON.

Comment: this will parse the json to java object   gson.fromJson("your json string", "your class");

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the full example of what the question is asking for. What is "your class" in this case?

Comment: gson.fromJson(json, uom_VO.class) this has worked for me