# Can't use (google.gson) jsonParser to parse string as jsonObject

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

I want to  parse  my  string  input  as  a  json and  then  get items  from it  for   this  reason  i have added  this  code:

```
String data=new String(content.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
         String x=data.replaceAll("[\\n\\r\\t]+", "");
         System.out.println(x+"=================================================");
        FormatedData="id:"+id+"\n"+"name:"+name+"\n"+"comment:"+comment;
         String id,name,comment;

         JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

              System.out.println(x+"===================================================");
                JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) parser.parse(x).getAsJsonObject();
                System.out.println(obj+"===============================================");
                  name = obj.get("organizationNameEN").getAsString();
                  id = obj.get("id").getAsString();
                  comment=obj.get("comment").getAsString();

         String FormatedData="id:"+id+"\n"+"name:"+name+"\n"+"comment:"+comment;
```

here  is  my JsonData:

```
{id:15, organizationNameGE:55, organizationNameEN:5656, cardNumber:6767, startDate:02/04/2018, period:5, endDate:02/10/2018, priority:not so important, $$hashKey:19A, comment:comment, mail:mail}
```

I am  useing  this  library  for  parsing com.google.gson.JsonParser;  but  when  i try  to make  this  operation i  got  this error:
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 89 path $.startDate
I HVAE  REMOVED  ALL  SPACES  FROM STRING  WHAT  SHOULD  I  CHENAGE  HERE  TO  GET  RID  OF  THIS  ERROR?

Comment: What is output of System.out.println(x+"=================================================");

Comment: it  will print  my  json  plus  this  symbols  "==============="

Comment: i want your json data. Can you post it?

Comment: I  HAVE  ADDED  JSON CONTENT IN MAIN QUESTION

Comment: Your posted json format is not a valid json. {id:15, organizationNameGE:55, organizationNameEN:5656, cardNumber:6767, startDate:'02/04/2018', period:5, endDate:'02/10/2018', priority:'not so important', $$hashKey:'19A', comment:'comment', mail:'mail'}\n string must be in single quote for poper json.

Comment: you can map JSON to a POJO using GSON
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039511/mapping-json-into-pojo-using-gson?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I  have  used  this  example   but this  error  is still here  com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException:

Comment: then your json must not be valid check it here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/